# Prove/disprove: $\forall f\ \in \mathbb N ^{\mathbb R}. \forall x\in \mathbb R. \exists y\in \mathbb R ((f(x)=f(y))\wedge (x\neq y))$

Tags: functions, logic, predicate-logic

> Prove/disprove: $\forall f\ \in \mathbb N ^{\mathbb R}. \forall x\in \mathbb R. \exists y\in \mathbb R ((f(x)=f(y))\wedge (x\neq y))$

This statement looks very similar to the definition of injective function but it has $\exists y$ instead for all, so I think it's false, take $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor$ then the statement is false $\forall x\ge 1$.

I also tried to make it harder and prove:

> $\forall f\ \in \mathbb N ^{\mathbb R}. \forall x,y \in \mathbb R ((f(x)=f(y))\wedge (x\neq y))$

Which I think is true, since the reals are compact and the cardinalities are different, is the way to do this is to suppose there exists a function such that $f(x)=f(y)\to x=y$? but I don't see how to reach the contradiction..

Comment: How is your example of the floor function a counterexample? We certainly have that $$\;\forall\;x\in\Bbb R\;\exists\,y\in\Bbb R\;\;s.t.\;\;f(x)=f(y)\;\wedge\;x\neq y\;$$

Comment: The first statement says that every function (from the reals to the naturals) is not-injective. The second one says that every function (from the real numbers to the natural numbers) is constant.

Comment: @GitGud I disagree with the first claim you made. See my answer and compare to the initial assertion about the function. That initial assertion is saying more than just not injective.

Comment: @user2566092 You're right, I should have said that the first statement implies that every function is not-injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What happens if you map all real numbers to a given integer, except for one real number that you map to a different integer?

Comment: Then we have $f(x)=f(y)\wedge x\neq y$ for all the reals that map to the first integer.

Comment: Right but it fails for the remaining one real number $x$ that maps to a different integer!!!

Comment: I submit to you that it disproves all the claims. Check the first claim carefully with my example, considering the unique point $x$ that maps to a different integer. Then does there exist a $y$ such that...?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the negation of the proposition.
$$
\exists f\ \in \mathbb N ^{\mathbb R}. \exists x\in \mathbb R. \forall y\in \mathbb R ((f(x)\neq f(y))\vee (x= y))
$$
It is true. Just build a function with such property. For exemple, 
$$
f(x)=
\left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & \mbox{ if } x=0,\\
\left\lfloor x \right\rfloor^2+1 & \mbox{ if  } x\neq 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
So if the negation is true the statement is false.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the statement isn't true. Then, as you noted, there exists a function $\;f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb N\;$ which is injective.

But then this carries that $\;2^{\aleph_0}=|\Bbb R|\le|\Bbb N|=\aleph_0\;$ , and this is very not true.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without the cardinalities?

Comment: I suppose there is, but why not?